# EF Core TPH, Discriminator is ignored when getting base entities

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Just to be clear: I saw a question with a similar title but from what i read it was the other way around.

So i have `baseEntity` and `subEntity` which derives from `baseEntity`. both (base and sub) entities are in dbContext and ef core automatically creates default discriminator property. Adding any of them properly sets Discriminator value to either "baseEntity" or "subEntity".

When i try to get list of sub-entities with `DbContext.Set<SubEntity>().ToList()` it works fine, returning only sub-entities (records where discriminator equals "SubEntity"). The problem is when i try to get list of base entities with `DbContext.Set<BaseEntity>().ToList()`. It ignores discriminator and returns not only records with "BaseEntity" in the discriminator field but also the ones with "SubEntity" discriminator.

How to return only entities with "BaseEntity" discriminator?
It could probably help if I had two subEntities deriving from base one and having only them inside dbContext, but one entity would be completely empty because everything is already in the base entity so I would like to avoid this solution.

Comment: Please provide us code with your `base entity` model and your `sub entity` model, to help us understand you question better.

Comment: `SubEntity` inherits (thus **is a**) `BaseEntity`. That's why `Set<BaseEntity` includes all derived types. There is no way to query for exact type, EF Core basically does the equivalent of `OfType` LINQ method, which is criteria based on `is` operator, e.g. `Where(entity => entity is SomeType)`